# Issue Migrating to Android X

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx

I am running into an issue migrating my project to Android X. After migrating my project and trying to build it, this is the error that I am getting:

`/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:2239: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/pivotX' with config ''.`

I am wondering if anyone else has experienced this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. What happened when I migrated to Android X was that some of the dependencies were mapped to the `alpha` channel instead of the `stable` one. Had to go through each dependency and map them myself. Luckily, Android has a link with all the `com.android` dependencies alongside the `androidx.` ones. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate